# Automatically refreshing a page at set interval using AJAX and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to refresh a page at a interval of 5 seconds which should update the view with latest data from the SQL Server. Below is the code.

```
@model Test.Data.Domain.ManufacturingCdMachine
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Rimage Details";
    ViewBag.JobId = Model.CurrentManufacturingJobId;
}
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="CdMachineDetails">
        @if (@Model.CurrentManufacturingJobId != null)
        {
            <div>
                @{Html.RenderPartial("_CdMachineJob");}
            </div>
        }
        else
        {
            <div>
                @{Html.RenderPartial("_MachineInIdle");}
            </div>
        }
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(
            function() {
                setInterval(function() {
                    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "/Mobile/CdMachine/Details/" + @Model.ManufacturingCdMachineId,
                        data: {

                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            //Sets your content into your div
                            $('#CdMachineDetails').html(result);
                        }
                    });

                }, 5000);
            });
</script>
```

The URL of my page is http://localhost:28886/Mobile/CdMachine/Details/1

However the page not seem to be refreshing.  What am I doing wrong?

-Alan-

Comment: What does the variable result contain

Comment: Please try to add `console.log(result)` inside `success` and tell us what is the output.

Comment: Well, http://localhost:28886 ist not too helpful as an URL. Maybe you put it online somewhere? Or even better create a runnable code snipped here.

Comment: I have fixed that issue. It throws an exception because of invalid variable. However I am getting flickering screen and the page become frozen after a while.

Answer (score -1):

1. you have syntax error in your JS. I think you are missing bracket at the end of your JS code.
2. Ajax doesn't refresh page - you just get content which you can of course place on the DOM or can manipulate it as you wish.
3. URL pointing to your localhost server will not work of course - must be placed public.

Comment: #3 is of course incorrect, so is #1, and for #2 he is already doing that.